# Fastlane gradle command - properties not passed

Tags: android, gradle, fastlane

I created a `fastlane` task for uploading to the Play Store as follows:

```
  lane :DEPLOY_BETA do

  gradle(task: "clean")

  version_codes = google_play_track_version_codes(
      package_name: "",
      json_key: "play_store_service_account_key.json",
  )

  gradle(
    task: "assemble",
    flavor: "World",
    build_type: "Release",
    properties: { "versionCode" => 100 }
  )

  apk_path = Actions.lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH]
  supply(
    apk: apk_path,
    json_key: "play_store_service_account_key.json",
    package_name: "",
    track: "beta",
    skip_upload_metadata: true,
    validate_only: true,
    skip_upload_images: true,
    skip_upload_screenshots: true
    )

  end
```

The problem is that the property `versionCode` doesn't override the `versionCode` specified in the flavor(nor defaultConfig). Is this a bug in fastlane? If i don't set the `versionCode` in `build.gradle` at all it simply adds no `versionCode` and fastlane supply will fail.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. And you have to use them inside your `build.gradle`, something like this:

`versionCode project.hasProperty('versionCode') ? project.property('versionCode') as int : 1
versionName project.hasProperty('versionName') ? project.property('versionName') : "No versionName"`

I found [this comment](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/1082#issuecomment-216638209) inside the [original pull request](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/1082). Seems like gradle don't expose those directly and we need to assign them manually (as per [this comment](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/1082#issuecomment-216624602)).

Answer (score 1):

just to confirm this behaviour, it seems you have to define versionName and/or versionCode in the build.gradle as @sebleclerc said.

```
# android/app/build.gradle
android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        // Fastlane will handle version
        versionName project.hasProperty('versionName') ? project.property('versionName') : "0.0.0"
        versionCode 0
    }
    ....
}
```

```
# android/fastlane/Fastfile
platform :android do
  lane :dev do
    code = google_play_track_version_codes(package_name: "my.package.name")
    code_incremented = code[0] + 1
    increment_version_code(
      gradle_file_path: "app/build.gradle", version_code: code_incremented
    )
    gradle(
      task: "clean assemble",
      flavor: "Development",
      build_type: "Release",
      properties: {
        "versionName" => ENV['APP_VERSION'],
      }
    )
    upload_to_play_store(
      package_name: "my.package.name",
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but got the same problem today and figured out that the new Gradle version causes this problem.

Version `7.3.0` and higher have this issue.
You can fix this by using a version below, i used `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'` in my project's build.gradle.

after this you can use:

```
gradle(
   task: 'assemble',
   build_type: 'Release',
   flags: "--warning-mode none -x lint",
   properties: {
       "android.injected.version.code" => versionCode,
       "android.injected.version.name" => versionName,
   }
)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the same issue for my project with the latest gradle wrapper 7.5,  gradle version 7.4.2 . I tried the below workaround:

1. In my build.gradle file, I changed the default config to read from gradle.properties file:

```
defaultConfig {
        ......
        versionCode = rootProject.ext.get("versionCode").toString().toInt()
        versionName = rootProject.ext.get("versionName").toString()
        ......
}
```

2. In my gradle.properties file (which exists in root directory), I defined the default values for these 2 properties:

```
versionCode=1
versionName=debug
```

3. Then run the assemble/bundle command using flags to modify these properties will generate apk/aab with required values (2, test):

```
 ./gradlew assembleMobileAlphaDebug -PversionCode=2 -PversionName=test
```

Please note I used versionCode and versionName as property names in all places, the property name should match.

Comment: Downgrading gradle was not a workaround for me.